# Storing values in an N x N grid

Tags: array, haskell

I am trying to write a program to store/display a grid of size N x N with cells containing either a 1 or a 0 in preparation for further computation:

```
module Board where

import Data.List as List

data CellState = One | Zero deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Cell = Cell {cellPos :: (Int, Int), cellState :: CellState} deriving (Eq, Ord)

type Board = [Cell]

instance Show CellState where
  show One = "1"
  show Zero = "0"

instance Show Cell where
  show (Cell c x) = show (c,x)

genPositions :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
genPositions x = [ (a,b) | a <- [0..(x-1)], b <- [0..(x-1)] ]

genCellState :: Int -> CellState
genCellState 0 = Zero
genCellState 1 = One

newBoard :: Int -> [Int] -> Board
newBoard i [x] = [Cell (round $ sqrt(fromIntegral i), round $ sqrt(fromIntegral i)) (genCellState x)]
  where positions = genPositions $ round $ sqrt(fromIntegral i)
newBoard i (x : xs) = [Cell (positions!!(i - 1 - length xs)) (genCellState x)] ++ newBoard i xs
  where positions = genPositions $ round $ sqrt(fromIntegral i)
```

What improvements can I make to this, both in terms of good practises and performance? I don't like Board being a list of Cells. I posted this on Stack Overflow by accident (have since deleted it) and someone recommended changing `type Board = [Cell]` to `newtype Board = Board { getBoard :: Array (Int,Int) CellState }` but I'm not too familiar with arrays in Haskell so not sure how this would work exactly. From what I have read they apply a function to the elements in the range `[Int..Int]` and return a list of tuples with the input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining `r = round . sqrt . fromIntegral`, `newBoard` fits on the screen. `positions` doesn't appear to be used in `newboard`'s first case.

Half the code disappears if we interpret `Cell` as `((Int, Int), Int)`.

`newBoard`'s first case can be pushed one recursion call deeper, mapping `[]` to `[]` instead of `[x]` to the current right hand side.

`[_] ++ _` should be simplified as `_ : _`.

`positions` is only used once, therefore I inline it.

```
type Cell = ((Int, Int), Int) -- (position, state)

genPositions :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
genPositions x = [ (a,b) | a <- [0..(x-1)], b <- [0..(x-1)] ]

r = round . sqrt . fromIntegral

newBoard :: Int -> [Int] -> [Cell]
newBoard i [] = []
newBoard i (x : xs) = (genPositions (r i)!!(i - 1 - length xs), x) : newBoard i xs
```

Successive elements of the list returned by `genPositions` and `xs` are zipped together; `zip` captures this pattern. `i` is now not needed in its non-rooted form and I recommend changing the interface to take `N` as an argument instead. Non-square arguments can currently crash `!!` anyway. `genPositions` is only used once, therefore I inline it.

```
type Cell = ((Int, Int), Int) -- (position, state)

newBoard :: Int -> [Int] -> [Cell]
newBoard n = zip $ liftA2 (,) [0..n-1] [0..n-1]
```

For `type Board = Array (Int, Int) Int`, Data.Array allows `newBoard n = listArray ((0,0),(n-1,n-1))`.